# Quadratic form plus linear for is a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, normal-distribution, quadratic-forms

I am searching for a way to reduce the following expression:

$$
\frac{1}{2}(y-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(y-\mu) - x^TP^Ty= \frac{1}{2}(y-\tilde{\mu})^T\tilde{\Sigma}^{-1}(y-\tilde{\mu})
$$
I need to find a closed form expression of $\tilde{\mu}$ and $\tilde{\Sigma}$, I was tolde that this is possible by using normalization, but I have tried to complete the squares and some others things but it didn't help. I considered $\Sigma$ as an $n\times n$ diagonal matrix, and $P$ is a orthogonal matrix of the same dimensions, $x, y$ and $\mu$ are vectors of dimension $n \times 1$. I would appreciate any help or guidance with this. Thanks in advanzce.

Comment: Try to use $(x-y)^TA(x-y) = x^TAx - 2y^TAx + y^TAy$ where $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: Thanks I will try